# SQL-EX.ru query problemset #32

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm trying to write an SQL query to solve a question at www.sql-ex.ru (Q. 32), I got the correct result, but the website validates my query as an undesirable solution. (it could be for all sorts of reasons: error in logic or ineffiency etc...)

**The schema**

http://www.sql-ex.ru/images/ships.gif

**SQL Query Question:**

> One of characteristics of a ship is one-half cube of calibre of its main guns (mw). Within 2 decimal places, define the average value of mw for the ships of each country which has ships in database.

**Website note on data**

> The database of naval ships that took part in World War II is under consideration. The database has the following relations:
>   Classes(class, type, country, numGuns, bore, displacement)
>   Ships(name, class, launched)
>   Battles(name, date)
>   Outcomes(ship, battle, result)
>   Ships in classes are arranged to a single project. A class is normally assigned the name of the first ship in the class under consideration (head ship); otherwise, the class name does not coincide with any ship name in the database.
>   The Classes relation includes the class name, type (bb for a battle ship, or bc for a battle cruiser), country where the ship was built, number of main guns, gun caliber (diameter of the gun barrel, in inches), and displacement (weight in tons). The Ships relation includes the ship name, its class name, and launch year. The Battles relation covers the name and date of a battle the ships participated; while the result of their participation in the battle (sunk, damaged, or unharmed - OK) is in the Outcomes relation.
>   Notes: 1) Outcomes relation may include the ships not included in the Ships relation. 2) Sunk ship can not participate in battles after that.

**My query**

```
            SELECT c.country, CAST( AVG(0.5*POWER(c.bore,3.0) ) AS DECIMAL(10,2) )
            AS  weight FROM
    (
    SELECT ship FROM Outcomes
    INTERSECT
    SELECT class FROM Classes
    EXCEPT
    SELECT class FROM Ships
    UNION ALL
    SELECT class FROM Ships

    ) AS cte1

    LEFT OUTER JOIN Classes AS c
    ON cte1.ship=c.class
    GROUP BY country
```

**Correct Result**

> country    weight
>
> Germany    1687.50
>
> Gt.Britain 1687.50
>
> USA    1897.78

**My question:**
How is my query incorrect given it yields the correct result? Many thanks.

Comment: Maybe asking at sql-ex.ru would make more sense.

Comment: Absolutely right, but access to question discussion on the forums is given only when a correct answer is provided. :(

Answer (score 3):

```
select country, convert(numeric(10, 2), avg(power(bore, 3)/2)) weight 
from
    (select country, bore, name from classes c, ships s
     where s.class=c.class
     union
     select country, bore, ship from classes c, outcomes o
     where o.ship=c.class 
     and o.ship not in(select distinct name from ships))x
group by country
```

Comment: Can you explain your query, so other people can understand how this fully solves the OP's question?

Answer (score 2):

The exercise itself is faulty (IMO).

What you suppose to do is JOIN the two tables, Classes and Ships, based on their Class, and calculate the average weight based on the actual amount of ships there are.

Yet there's a few problems:

1. There is a ship class (Bismark) that appears in the classes table but not in the ships table. Apparently you have to take this also into account even though it doesn't exist. One might argue how can you include an average of ships actually existing together with an hypothetical average of ships that don't actually exist?

If you do take this into account, you will pass the 1st DB but not the 2nd. Why? Because of the 2nd problem:

2. In order to pass completely, you also have to take into account the ships *names* that appear in the Outcomes table, and join them on the classes with outcomes.names = classes.class. Why? No idea. Bismark is the only "name" of a ship in outcomes that is also a "name" of a class in classes. Why should they be joined? Who knows. How are you supposed to guess that? Well... I have no clue. It makes NO SENSE.

So, the 2 problems are quite illogical (IMO), and while the 1st one is somewhat ok, the 2nd one is completely absurd.

This, for example, solved the 1st db but failed the 2nd:

```
--t1, t1_2, t1_3 are creating a class table with count of no. of ships. Any ship appearing only in the classes table would be assigned a count of 1.
with t1 as 
(Select class, count(name) 'c1' from ships group by class),
t1_2 as
(select ship 'class', 1 'c1' from outcomes where ship not in (select class from t1)),
t1_3 as
(select * from t1 union select * from t1_2),

t2 as
(select distinct classes.class, country, 0.5*bore*bore*bore 'mw', c1 from classes left join t1_3 on t1_3.class = classes.class)
select country, cast(sum(mw*c1)/sum(c1) as decimal(10,2)) from t2 group by country
```

And this solves it completely:

```
with t1 as
(select country, bore, name from classes, ships
where classes.class=ships.class
union
select country, bore, ship 'name' from classes, outcomes
where classes.class = outcomes.ship)
select country, cast(avg(0.5*bore*bore*bore) as decimal(10,2)) 'mw' 
from t1 group by country
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNTRY, CONVERT(NUMERIC(10,2),AVG(BORE*BORE*BORE/2)) WEIGHT 
FROM (SELECT COUNTRY,BORE,NAME
    FROM CLASSES 
    RIGHT JOIN SHIPS ON SHIPS.CLASS = CLASSES.CLASS
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT COUNTRY, BORE, SHIP
    FROM CLASSES C 
    LEFT JOIN OUTCOMES O ON O.SHIP = C.CLASS 
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT NAME 
    FROM SHIPS 
    WHERE NAME = O.SHIP) AND 
    NOT (SHIP IS NULL)
 )T
GROUP BY COUNTRY
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, i have made this query and it yiels correcty result, but is is not accepted by the page.

`select c.country, convert(numeric(10, 2), avg(power(bore, 3)/2)) as weight from classes as c
    left join ships as s on (s.class = c.class)
    group by c.country`

My thoughts are that you can only calculate correct answer on classes that exists in classes(for which you have the numbers), so outcomes for me is useless table in this case (no point retreiving classes of ships that we dont have data for), because you can select number of ships of each class from ship table, and calculate all the fields from the given data.. And main class like bismarck is solved by left join, which is only one ship of its given type anyway..

`select country, convert(numeric(10, 2), avg(power(bore, 3)/2)) as weight from classes
inner join (SELECT Ships.name, Ships.class FROM Ships inner join Classes ON Ships.class = Classes.class
union 
SELECT Outcomes.ship, Classes.class FROM Outcomes inner join  Classes ON Outcomes.ship = Classes.class
) as ships
on (ships.class = classes.class)
group by country`

This is the correct answer, the difference is that there might be ships in outcomes that are not in ship table, even though they are not. So you have to account for that

Answer (score 0):

Let's decompose your query:

1. Computations and data selection: absolutely correct. Task definition says: `One of characteristics of a ship is one-half cube of caliber of its main guns (mw). Within 2 decimal places, define the average value of mw for the ships of each country...`
2. You could've get rid of one logical operation (`INTERSECT`) if you replace your `LEFT OUTER JOIN` with the `INNER JOIN` (which also filter out unmatched data, as `INTERSECT` does as well). So, your query would look like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    c.country, 
    CAST(AVG(0.5*POWER(c.bore, 3)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS weight 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ship FROM Outcomes
        EXCEPT
        SELECT class FROM Ships
        UNION ALL
        SELECT class FROM Ships
    )   cte1
        INNER JOIN 
        Classes c
            ON cte1.ship = c.class
    GROUP BY c.country;
```

3. Now let's prepare golden dataset to test our solution. Let's assume we have these classes:

- A (will be contained in the `Ships`, `Classes`, `Outcomes` tables)
- B (will be contained in the `Ships`, `Classes` tables)
- C (will be contained in the `Ships`, `Outcomes` tables)
- D (will be contained in the `Classes`, `Outcomes` tables)
- E (will be contained in the `Ships` table)
- F (will be contained in the `Classes` table)
- G (will be contained in the `Outcomes` table)

Now let's take into account DB definition and get rid of classes C and E as we cannot hold them in the `Ships` table but not in the `Classes` table (FK constraint).
OK, now let's prepare test data (uninteresting data will be presented as `...`):

Table `Outcomes`:

| ship | battle | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | ... | ... |
| C | ... | ... |
| D | ... | ... |
| G | ... | ... |

Table `Ships`:

| name | class | launched |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ... | A | ... |
| ... | B | ... |

Table `Classes`:

| class | type | country | numGuns | bore | displacement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | ... | USA | ... | 5 | ... |
| B | ... | Canada | ... | 10 | ... |
| D | ... | Spain | ... | 15 | ... |
| F | ... | Japan | ... | 20 | ... |

Table `Battles` is not described here as we are not interested in it at all.

4. Now let's apply your solution to this dataset:

```sql
SELECT ship FROM Outcomes  -- 1) Will result: A, C, D, G
EXCEPT                     -- 3) Will result: C, G
SELECT class FROM Ships    -- 2) Will result: A, B, D, F
UNION ALL                  -- 5) Will result: A, B, C, G
SELECT class FROM Ships    -- 4) Will result: A, B

-- Final set (5):  A, B, C, G
```

Then goes the join operation and bla-bla-bla, all good (see next point).

5. But what if we have this set:

Table `Outcomes`:

| ship | battle | result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | ... | ... |
| A | ... | ... |
| A10 | ... | ... |
| C | ... | ... |
| D | ... | ... |
| G | ... | ... |

Table `Ships`:

| name | class | launched |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A10 | A | ... |
| A20 | A | ... |
| B | B | ... |

Table `Classes`:

| class | type | country | numGuns | bore | displacement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | ... | USA | ... | 5 | ... |
| B | ... | Canada | ... | 10 | ... |
| D | ... | Spain | ... | 15 | ... |
| F | ... | Japan | ... | 20 | ... |

So, the point is task definition says you also need to consider SHIPS (NOT CLASSES) from the `Outcomes` table even if they (SHIPS) are not presented in the `Ships` table. So, you need to replace one of your selects:

```sql
SELECT 
    c.country, 
    CAST(AVG(0.5*POWER(c.bore, 3)) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS weight 
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ship FROM Outcomes
        EXCEPT
        SELECT class FROM Ships  -- Change this one to select ship names (not classes).
        UNION ALL
        SELECT class FROM Ships
    )   cte1
        INNER JOIN 
        Classes c
            ON cte1.ship = c.class
    GROUP BY c.country;
```

6. Final solution could've look like this (considering the last set):

```sql
-- Your variant:
SELECT 
    cl.country                                       AS country,
    CAST(AVG(POWER(cl.bore, 3)/2) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS avg_mw
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ship FROM Outcomes  -- 1) Will result: A, A, A10, C, D, G
        EXCEPT                     -- 3) Will result: A, C, D, G
        SELECT name FROM Ships     -- 2) Will result: A10, A20, B
        UNION ALL                  -- 5) Will result: A, B, C, D, G
        SELECT class FROM Ships    -- 4) Will result: A, B
    )   clnm  -- Classes (if head ships) and names.
        INNER JOIN
        Classes cl
            ON clnm.ship = cl.class
    GROUP BY cl.country;
```

Or like this:

```
-- My solution:
SELECT 
    cl.country                                       AS country,
    CAST(AVG(POWER(cl.bore, 3)/2) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS avg_mw
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT out.ship AS class  -- 1, 2, 3) Will result: A, C, D, G
            FROM Outcomes out
            WHERE out.ship NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT sh.name FROM Ships sh)
        UNION ALL                  -- 5) Will result: A, B, C, D, G
        SELECT class FROM Ships    -- 4) Will result: A, B
    )   clnm  -- Classes (if head ships) and names.
        INNER JOIN
        Classes cl
            ON clnm.class = cl.class
    GROUP BY cl.country;
```

Answer (score 0):

I Spent quite some time trying to figure out how to solve this challenge and I guess I now finally understand how to solve it.

Here is my solution:

```
select country, round(avg(bore^3/2)::numeric, 2) from (
  select c.country, c.bore, s.name
  from ships s join classes c on s.class = c.class
  union all
  select distinct c.country, c.bore, o.ship
  from outcomes o join classes c on o.ship = c.class
  where o.ship not in (select name from ships)
) _ group by country;
```

So my first idea was to simply join `classes` table and `ships` table on `class` and call it a day since it makes sense:

```
select country, round(avg(bore^3/2)::numeric, 2) from (
  select c.country, c.bore
  from ships s join classes c
  on s.class = c.class
) _ group by country;
```

However, this doesn't work because we have to also take into account the ships from `Outcomes` table, as stated in the database description:

> 4. A ship found in the Outcomes table but not in the Ships table is still considered in the database. This is true even if it is sunk.

And I suppose that also makes sense because of this:

> A class is normally assigned either the name of the first ship built according to the corresponding design, or a name that is different from any ship name in the database. The ship whose name is assigned to a class is called a lead ship.

I suppose the infamous "Bismark" ship is exactly that - the first ship built in its class.

So we should simply add ships that are mentioned in the `Outcomes` table but are not present in the `Ships` table then:

```
select country, round(avg(bore^3/2)::numeric, 2) from (
  select c.country, c.bore
  from ships s join classes c on s.class = c.class
  union all
  select c.country, c.bore
  from outcomes o join classes c on o.ship = c.class
  where o.ship not in (select name from ships)
) _ group by country;
```

And it almost works (it passes the first database). And it took me some time to understand why this solution doesn't work but [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29788354/17694538) does. My best guess is that in the second DB, some ships that are present in the `Outcome` table and not present in the `Ships` table are mentioned there multiple times (e.g. a given ship participated in multiple battles). So we have to deduplicate by ship name and for that reason add it as an additional column to the result set and then use either `union` or `union all` together with `select distinct` on `Outcomes`-`Classes` join, which is what I ended up doing and it just makes the solution more clear to me.